# openai unknown command 'tools'

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, fine-tuning

- I am learning gpt fine-tuning
- I successfully ran this command: pip install --upgrade openai
- I couldn't run this command: export OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
- Error: export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
- So I ran this command instead: set OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
- Also ran Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
- Now I'm trying to run openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f C:\Users.....fine-tune-upload.xlsx

But it shows: error: unknown command 'tools'

Any idea? Please explain in beginner language!

Comment: Where did you get the idea that _would_ work? All of the CLI examples in https://pypi.org/project/openai/ start with `openai api ...`

Answer (score 0):

**Use Linux** to run the commands

Or

If you want to use it in **Windows** follow the below instruction:

Install [WSL](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P9TQF7MRM4R) (Windows Subsystem for Linux) from Microsoft Store,

Then, Enable `Windows Subsystem for Linux`:

To enable it :

- Open Start Menu and search for "Turn Windows features on or off"
- Then scroll down and check `Windows Subsystem for Linux`
  Then you will asked to restart, After restarting Open `CMD` from the Start menu.

And write the following command `wsl --install` after installing it just write `wsl` command.

Finally, you can follow [OpenAI instruction](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/installation) and they will work fine.